# C# Cannot pass as a ref

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was trying out programming in C# with EMGUCV when I ran into this error:

Error   1   Cannot pass 'currentFrameBlob' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Error   2   Cannot pass 'currentFrameBlob' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

It is located in this code block.

```
public void matchCurrentFrameBlobsToExistingBlobs(ref List<Blob> existingBlobs, ref List<Blob> currentFrameBlobs)
{
    foreach (Blob existingBlob in existingBlobs)
    {
        existingBlob.blnCurrentMatchFoundOrNewBlob = false;
        existingBlob.predictNextPosition();
    }

    foreach (Blob currentFrameBlob in currentFrameBlobs)
    {
        int intIndexOfLeastDistance = 0;
        double dblLeastDistance = 1000000.0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= existingBlobs.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((existingBlobs[i].blnStillBeingTracked == true))
            {
                double dblDistance = distanceBetweenPoints(currentFrameBlob.centerPositions.Last(), existingBlobs[i].predictedNextPosition);

                if ((dblDistance < dblLeastDistance))
                {
                    dblLeastDistance = dblDistance;
                    intIndexOfLeastDistance = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((dblLeastDistance < currentFrameBlob.dblCurrentDiagonalSize * 0.5))
        {
            addBlobToExistingBlobs(ref currentFrameBlob, ref existingBlobs, ref intIndexOfLeastDistance);
        }
        else
        {
            addNewBlob(ref currentFrameBlob, ref existingBlobs);
        }
    }
```

I read about the error and it seems to me that this is one of those quirks of C#. What is the most efficient way of dealing with this type of error. Right now I'm quite afraid of making changes since I have very little idea on how to go about solving it without making it worse.

Comment: First question to answer - do you really need to be passing these things by reference?

Comment: My god, you are using `ref` everywhere

Comment: you need to read up o `ref` and how to and when to use them also show where and how you are declaring the `existingBlobs && currentFrameBlobs` I really don't think you need to declare them as `ref`

Comment: I second @AntP. Remember that in C# *all* class variables are references; that may come as a surprise to people migrating from, say, C or C++. If you leave out the `ref`, the arguments are still references, and any changes the functions make to the objects will be visible to the caller.  I doubt that you want to *change what `currentFrameBlob` refers to* (which would be the meaning of passing a `ref` reference, and quite nonsensical for a loop variable, which is why it is impossible).

Comment: We were studying C++ (using the old Turbo) and VB in VS 2013 before coming into C#. Some of our old habits might have creeped in. My partner did that in VB (using VS2013) before I converted it into C# using an online converter.

This is the first time I've seen this error, that's the source of my hesitation at first but then I realized I could just back-up the entire program. Embarrassing mistake.

Would showing the entire code here help? I suspect that the reason my partner used ref has something to do with the class he used.

Comment: Found the source of the errors. It was an extra ref in the definition addBlobToExistingBlobs. I removed it and the line where the error is located. I did the same thing with the other. Application is now working.

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score -3):

Simplest fix:

```
 foreach (Blob currentFrameBlob2 in currentFrameBlobs)
 {
   Blob currentFrameBlob = currentFrameBlob2;
   //....
```

Comment: yes but the real question one should be asking is why is the OP passing anything by ref the OP should read up on `ref keyword in msdn`

Comment: But that wasn't what he was asking. He was afraid of making big changes.

Comment: Being afraid will get you nowhere in programming, at least until the year 2997 when they start looking for retired c# winforms programmers to fix the Y3k problems.

Comment: I still feel that this answers "What is the most efficient way of dealing with this type of error." It's definately not good code, but it'll work. Also it's not even clear if he could change the signatures of those functions.

Comment: The thing is it likely won't work - it will *compile* but this does not actually provide a solution of any meaningful form.